# Failed to parse application numbers from a map using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape information from a [map](http://gisportal.campbellriver.ca/arcgis2/apps/PublicInformation/index.html?appid=cf6f6aeaeceb4db5ac2434e2cff00e14) using requests module. The information I'm after are in several [box like containers](https://ibb.co/gjsjrWp), which pops up when the yellow colored area on the map is clicked. I wish to parse the `application number` from each of the boxes.

I tried to observe network activity in dev tools to find out any such link which contains the required information but I failed.

The following is how I've created the script but I ended up getting different information when I execute it:

```
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint

link = 'https://gisportal.campbellriver.ca/arcgis/rest/services/DevelApps_MuniBdry_Parcels/FeatureServer/1/query'

params = {
    'f': 'json',
    'returnGeometry': 'true',
    'spatialRel': 'esriSpatialRelIntersects',
    'geometry': '{"xmin":-13971465.778085683,"ymin":6418264.391068123,"xmax":-13932330.019603727,"ymax":6457400.14955008,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}}',
    'geometryType': 'esriGeometryEnvelope',
    'inSR': '102100',
    'outFields': '*',
    'outSR': '102100',
    'resultType': 'tile',
    'quantizationParameters': '{"mode":"view","originPosition":"upperLeft","tolerance":76.43702828507084,"extent":{"xmin":-13970672.893748092,"ymin":6429207.023229747,"xmax":-13936535.293969424,"ymax":6466884.27089714,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100,"latestWkid":3857}}}'
}
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link,params=params)
    for item in res.json()['features']:
        pprint(item['attributes'])
```

Current output (truncated):

```
'APPROX_HA': 17.68241328,
 'BCAssessVa': 111000,
 'COMPLETED': 'y',
 'DESCRIPTIO': 'Rural Two',
 'ELECTORAL': 'JUR336',
 'HOUSE': 0,
 'HTTP': 'http://GIS01/ParcelTifs/NoPlan.pdf',
 'HTTP1': 'http://webmap.campbellriver.ca/ZoningPdf/RU-2.pdf',
 'JUROLL': '0336029068.076',
 'LAST_UPDAT': 'JUL 15 2004',
 'LEGAL': 'SECTION 14  TOWNSHIP 2  COMOX LAND DISTRICT  PLAN VIP552A W 1/2 OF '
          'SE 1/4, MANAGED FOREST 0068.',
 'LINK_ID': 12399,
 'LOT': ' ',
 'LOT_DESC': 'ACRES',
 'LOT_SIZE': '80',
 'LTO_NUMBER': 'CA7321763'
```

Expected output:

```
Status                Received
Application number    P1800100
Type                  Official Community Plan Bylaw Amendment (OCP)
```

How can I scrape `Application Numbers` from [this map](http://gisportal.campbellriver.ca/arcgis2/apps/PublicInformation/index.html?appid=cf6f6aeaeceb4db5ac2434e2cff00e14) using requests?

Comment: Sounds like a javascript problem. Have you seen https://data-crcc.opendata.arcgis.com/

Comment: You'll have to use selenium to solve this one

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will be helpful.

I could find this [API](https://gisportal.campbellriver.ca/arcgis/rest/services/AllDevelopmentApplications/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&where=Type%20%3D%20%27Development%20Variance%20Permit%20(DVP)%27&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry=%7B%22xmin%22%3A-13942113.959215496%2C%22ymin%22%3A6437832.27029199%2C%22xmax%22%3A-13932330.019594997%2C%22ymax%22%3A6447616.20991249%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%7D%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=102100&outFields=*&returnCentroid=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=false&maxRecordCountFactor=3&outSR=102100&resultType=tile&quantizationParameters=%7B%22mode%22%3A%22view%22%2C%22originPosition%22%3A%22upperLeft%22%2C%22tolerance%22%3A19.10925707128908%2C%22extent%22%3A%7B%22xmin%22%3A-13942113.959215496%2C%22ymin%22%3A6437832.27029199%2C%22xmax%22%3A-13932330.019594995%2C%22ymax%22%3A6447616.20991249%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%7D%7D%7D)

You'll have to reverse engineer the input to get this output, but this should be a good start for you since you were using /DevelApps_MuniBdry_Parcels instead of /AllDevelopmentApplications.

Also [take a look at one of the first request made](https://gisportal.campbellriver.ca/arcgis/rest/services/DevelApps_MuniBdry_Parcels/FeatureServer/1/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry=%7B%22xmin%22%3A-13971465.77808553%2C%22ymin%22%3A6437832.270308757%2C%22xmax%22%3A-13951897.898844551%2C%22ymax%22%3A6457400.149549736%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%7D%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=102100&outFields=*&outSR=102100&resultType=tile&quantizationParameters=%7B%22mode%22%3A%22view%22%2C%22originPosition%22%3A%22upperLeft%22%2C%22tolerance%22%3A38.218514142536385%2C%22extent%22%3A%7B%22xmin%22%3A-13970672.893748092%2C%22ymin%22%3A6429207.023229747%2C%22xmax%22%3A-13936535.293969424%2C%22ymax%22%3A6466884.27089714%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A102100%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A3857%7D%7D%7D)

In summary, I think you should monitor the network tabs because it looks like they fetch all the data from their APIs and then use some logic to match your mouse click -> coordinate -> object which you should be able to do yourself without their frontend. would take some time though.